# Нужна ли авторизация (не явная) в API на php?

Tags: php

Передо мной поставили задачу. Написать на **API** к простому приложению на `php` реализованного по паттерну `MVC` и без применения какого-либо `frameworks`. Реализовал я его так:

- Добавил контроллер - `ApiController`;
- Добавил модель - `Api`;
- Добавил маршруты `/api/Equipments`, `/api/Personal`, `/api/AddProject`;

Далее я функцией `file_get_contents()` получаю входящие данные:

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

А теперь вопрос. Правильно ли передавать в `JSON` логин, пароль (не хэш) и токен  чтобы потом отдать данные которые относятся только к этому пользователю?

Пример проверки:

```
if(!array_key_exists('login', $user) || empty($user['login'])) throw new Exception('отсутствует или пуст ключ login');
if(!array_key_exists('password', $user) || empty($user['password'])) throw new Exception('отсутствует или пуст ключ password');
if(!array_key_exists('token', $user) || empty($user['token'])) throw new Exception('отсутствует или пуст ключ token');
```

Пример `JSON`:

```
{
   "login":"test",
   "password":"test1542",
   "token":"905bde212dcb5f2bb146f5d653166cd1"
}
```

Всё реализовано без использования `Json Web Token` `OAuth2`. Отсутствие данных технологий сильная дыра в безопасности?

Comment: Передавать пароль в открытом виде уже небезопасно. MitM перехватит его и получит доступ к вашему API.

Comment: @u_mulder Как тогда выдавать токен автоматически?

Comment: логин, пароль простым текстом и токен в одной пачке - у вас какое-то извращенное представление о неявной авторизации. А нужна ли она вам вообще - это надо смотреть по задаче